# how to pass case sensitive view_name to add_continuous_aggregate_policy()

Tags: timescaledb

I have hyper_table name with upper cases in it. Call to add_continuous_aggregate_policy fails in such cases with error saying relationship does not exist. Note, this works fine when hyper_table name is lower case:

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('iDU8boGyFcvWwfz6KhMSdg', start_offset => INTERVAL '1 months', end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour', schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hours'); 
ERROR:  relation "idu8bogyfcvwwfz6khmsdg" does not exist
```

Quoting it ends up treating it as a column:

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy("iDU8boGyFcvWwfz6KhMSdg", start_offset => INTERVAL '1 months', end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour', schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hours')
ERROR:  column "iDU8boGyFcvWwfz6KhMSdg" does not exist
```

Is there a way to pass case sensitive view name to

> add_continuous_aggregate_policy

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL will normalize any table name to lowercase unless it is quoted. If you enclose the string in both ' and " then it will work for you. To avoid issues down the line it's preferable to use only lower case, but if you have a need this is how to do it.

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('"iDU8boGyFcvWwfz6KhMSdg"',
```

The outer '  is because it is a text literal and the inner " is to mark it so it doesnt get lowercased. The same applies to any function where you want to force the case. It also applies across PostgreSQL not just to TimescaleDB.

*Transparency: I work for Timescale*